# Which class can I use to pass a "RecordSet" between an WinForm VB.Net EXE program and a classes DLL?

Tags: c#, vb.net, recordset, in-memory

I have developped a `VB.Net` DLL that can read `Postgres`, `Oracle` and `OleDb`.

To allow this DLL to execute some SQL commands, I pass it a `Connection` object and I use it to execute some SQL `SELECT` command.

My problem now is that I want to pass all data contained in a `GridView` object that contains data obtained using a `SQL` command in EXE program (not in DLL) **and that** user can have changed.

Which type of object can I pass considering following constraints ?

1. argument passed cannot be a WinForm control as `DataGridView` (no Winform object in DLL)
2. another database's table cannot be filled with `DataGridView` content (not performant)
3. class used must be part of an .Net assembly (not a `COM`, too old technology)

Until now, the only solution found consist of using `ADO` or `Microsoft ActiveX Data Object Record Set`, but this class is not an .Net assembly and solution found on [DataBase Journal](https://www.databasejournal.com/ms-access/create-in-memory-ado-recordsets/) does'nt work because `Items` property of `Field` class is Read Only.

Here is my code

```
    Dim rstADO As ADODB.Recordset
    rstADO = New ADODB.Recordset
    With rstADO
        .Fields.Append("EmployeeID", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adInteger, 0, ADODB.FieldAttributeEnum.adFldKeyColumn)
        .Fields.Append("FirstName", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, 10, ADODB.FieldAttributeEnum.adFldMayBeNull)

        .CursorType = ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenKeyset
        .CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
        .LockType = ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockPessimistic
        .Open()

        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In grid.Rows
            .AddNew()
            For i = 0 To grid.Columns.Count - 1
                .Fields(i) = row.Cells(i).Value
            Next i
            .Update()
        Next row
    End With
```

Line `.Fields(i)` dispay following error
BC30526: 'Item' property is 'ReadOnly'.

Which class can I use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a .Net DataTable object.

Here is some lines of code

```
Dim dt As New DataTable

dt.Columns.Add("EmployeeID", GetType(Integer))
dt.Columns.Add("FirstName", GetType(String))

For Each row As DataGridViewRow In grid.Rows
    dt.Rows.Add(row.Cells(0), row.Cells(1))
Next row
```

and when it is filled, you can pass it to your DLL

```
SetDataTable(dt)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used solution proposed by `tramex` user.

I want to extract all columns except `Edit` et `PDF` columns and I need to add a special column named `cash` based on another column present in `DataGridView`.

Here is my code

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim sName As String
Dim type As Type

Dim oSKipList() As String = {"Edit", "PDF"}
For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In grid.Columns
    sName = col.Name.Replace("Col_", "")
    If Not oSKipList.Contains(sName) Then
        type = col.CellTemplate.FormattedValueType
        dt.Columns.Add(sName, type)
    End If
Next col
dt.Columns.Add("cash", Type.GetType("System.String"))

For Each row As DataGridViewRow In grid.Rows
    Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow
    Dim n = 0
    For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In grid.Columns
        sName = col.Name.Replace("Col_", "")
        If Not oSKipList.Contains(sName) Then
            Dim i = col.Index
            dr(n) = row.Cells(i).Value
            n += 1
        End If
    Next col
    dr(n) = IIf(dr("Account") = "-", "CASH", "")
    dt.Rows.Add(dr)
Next row

oExcelReport.SetDataTable(dt)
```

The first part of this code initialize Columns and the second part initialize Rows.

This code is working fine on my program.